# Convert Old Xcode Project to New

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Let's say I found some source code from 3 years ago but now it doesn't run right due to xcode changes.  Is there an easy and quick way to convert an old xcode project to work with the newest xcode?

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite simple way to always correctly uplift an old codebase.

It depends if it's ObjC or Swift.

It depends which version of Xcode you're moving to.

It depends on the libraries the project links against.

etc etc etc.

If you edit your question to be more specific you will get more help.